# AngularJS data binding not working - within the controller Scope variables are not showing the entered value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a strange situation in which `$scope` variables binding do not appear to be work as expected.

Here is the HTML:

```
        <div class="input-group" style="width:100px">
            <input type="number" 
                   class="form-control" 
                   id="Sampling_Request_for_Current_Sampling_INPUT"
                   ng-model="aabbcc" 
                   style="width:125px;text-align:center">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="Cannot_Allocate_Yet" ng-click="Get_Sampling_Request_Details()" type="button">{{All_Labels.Common.Display}}</button>
            </span>
        </div>
```

and here is the scope function invoked upon clicking on the button:

```
$scope.Get_Sampling_Request_Details = function () {
    console.log("$scope.aabbcc: " + $scope.aabbcc) ;
}
```

The variable `$scope.aabbcc` is initialized to `0` upon controller's loading.

Regardless what I type into the input element, I always get `0` in the console.

Comment: Can you show your full controller code?

Comment: Try passing aabbcc to your function and accessing that parameter in your js file

Comment: Thank you @iamalismith for your prompt reply. Unfortunately, company policy does not allow that. The interesting point is that the same page has other inputs connected to scope variables that would OK. This one, however, does not for some reason.

Comment: Maybe somewhere your model is getting changed.

Comment: @RishabhJain, that would be a **bypass** of the issue. variables declared using `ng-model` *SOULD* be updated and properly seen within the JS.

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://output.jsbin.com/lubihuv. Any errors in the `console`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This scenario generally happens, If you have wrapped your HTML inside `ng-if`, `ng-switch` `ng-repeat`.. or some other directive that creates `new child scope`.
See this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/erhym7tv/).

So it's a best practice to wrap your scope in some model to leverage protypical inheritance and correctly bind data to `$scope`.

Like : `$scope.data.aabbcc = 0` and use it like `ng-model ='data.aabbcc'`.

[See this for few minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m) and [Read this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) for complete understanding.

Comment: This seems like the most likely explanation to me

Comment: BINGO!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you. I would say that AngularJS should have a better "book keeping" mechanism... Still, great library. Thanks again @anoop!!!

Comment: glad to help you :) , [See this for few minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m) and [Read this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) for complete understanding.

Answer (score 1):

check this working example

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
Hello, {{name}}!
 <input type="number" ng-model="name"/>
 <button class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="Cannot_Allocate_Yet" ng-
 click="Get_Sampling_Request_Details()" type="button">test</button>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


 function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 0;
         $scope.Get_Sampling_Request_Details = function () {
console.log("$scope.aabbcc: " + $scope.name) ;
 }
 }
```

Comment: ... and I have quite many examples in the same project that work smoothly. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an empty object in your controller section .

```
eg: $scope.obj = {};
```

And use like  `ng-model="obj.key_name"` in your html. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS controllers control the data. The scope is the binding part between the HTML (view) and the JavaScript (controller). You must define the ng-model inside a ng-controller within which its scope lies. Try this out.

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div class="input-group" style="width:100px">
        <input type="number" 
               class="form-control" 
               id="Sampling_Request_for_Current_Sampling_INPUT"
               ng-model="aabbcc" 
               style="width:125px;text-align:center">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="Cannot_Allocate_Yet" ng-click="Get_Sampling_Request_Details()" type="button">{{All_Labels.Common.Display}}</button>
        </span>
</div>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('Myapp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.Get_Sampling_Request_Details = function () {
    console.log("$scope.aabbcc: " + $scope.aabbcc) ;
} 
});
</script>
```

Comment: As stated in one of my comments, there are plenty examples in my project that work perfectly well. Thanks for your answer anyway.