# AngularJs checkbox issue single variable

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angularjs v1. I want to know why I cannot assign a single variable scope into the md-checkbox. like

```
<md-checkbox ng-click="checkAllBox();" ng-model="chkValue" aria-label="Checkbox" style="float:left;margin-left:-4px;" class="md-primary"></md-checkbox>
```

;controller

```
$scope.chkValue = false;
```

which doesn't work (the $scope.chkValue didn't associate with the UI checkbox correctly). But the below is ok. May I know why?

```
<md-checkbox ng-click="checkAllBox();" ng-model="data.cb1" aria-label="Checkbox" style="float:left;margin-left:-4px;" class="md-primary"></md-checkbox>
```

;controller

```
$scope.data.cb1 = false;
```

Comment: always use a dot! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128323/if-you-are-not-using-a-dot-in-your-angularjs-models-you-are-doing-it-wrong :-)

Comment: See this [also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43997604/3455035).. :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are changing a variable from child scope the parent scope variable never changed.. Scope's has inheritance. You can get information from [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

**Edit**

To be more spesific. Controllers, some directives('ng-if', 'ng-include', vs.), isolate scopes creates its **own scope**.

If you want to referance a variable you need to use it with variables owner.

There is a live answer below. You can see controller has created its own scope and the parent scope cant detect changes because it has a different owner(this) now.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope){
  $scope.checkData = false;
})
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body  ng-app="app"  >
    parent1:<input ng-model="checkData" type="checkbox"/>
    
      <div class="child">
        <div class="child">
          <div class="innerChild">
            inner1:<input ng-model="checkData" type="checkbox"/>
          </div>
            <div class="innerChild">
              inner2:<input ng-model="checkData" type="checkbox"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    Controller Scope -><br>
parent2:<input ng-model="checkData" type="checkbox"/>
    <div ng-controller="ctrl" >
      <div class="child">
        <div class="child">
          <div class="innerChild">
            inner1:<input ng-model="checkData" type="checkbox"/>
          </div>
            <div class="innerChild">
              inner2:<input ng-model="checkData" type="checkbox"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <div class="innerChild">
          inner3:<input ng-model="checkData" type="checkbox"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: but why it works when i add change $scope.a to $scope.something.a ?

Comment: Because if you have referance to `$scope.something.a` then you can change something and the changes will be reflected but `$scope.a` is directly variable of `$scope` and if you change the `a`, ` $scope` must be in `transclude` tree.